# Who signed the Captain Picard Day sign?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, props, star-trek-picard

With the release of the trailers for *Star Trek: Picard* we have observed what either a flashback, or an in-universe reproduction or preserved artifact of the Captain Picard Day sign.  This also affords us some much higher resolution views of this in-universe object.

Original TNG:

[image: big multicolored sign as seen in TNG]

*Star Trek: Picard* trailer:

[image: new version of the above]

And furthermore, this banner (or another reproduction) was on display at the Captain Picard Museum at SDCC 2019, which purports to be an in-universe museum dedicated to the lifetime accomplishments of Captain/Admiral Picard

So, given the high-resolution views we now have of the banner:

- Which names can we tie to known children on the Enterprise-D?
- For non-Terran scripts, which can we tie to a known language?  Which can we read?

In short, **who signed the sign**?

Comment: Interesting, I believe this is pretty much the only time we see an Enterprise resident using a written language besides Earth script for day-to-day communication.

Comment: Again, with escaping the tick marks...by my account, we have: Mok, Tiamé, Ja'Lok Noq, [roughly Z\`3UƐ], Devyn, [roughly Z\`JOƮ3, same script as previous], BLitn, [W-with a line, kind-of-fancy-N, captial-I-with huge serifs], Robert, [tilty-W-with-a-dot, L'H-joined], [green-reptilian?-hand-print], Michael

Comment: Just FYI: they are not exactly the same banners.  The one in the trailer has more white space at the left edge and is also missing a purple signature below the green “a” in “Captain”, for instance.

Comment: @Praxis - Yes, the d in Picard is also wrong. It's pretty close though and someone's clearly taken a fair amount of time to try to get it right. Maybe the kids made multiple signs :-)

Comment: @Praxis, oh this is right.   To my list, we need add "Qudei" or something like that.  I guess this kid was retconned out.  Or perhaps *The universe is a spheroid region seven hundred and five metres in diameter.*  Uh oh.

Comment: Conversation about italicisation of ship names has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96547/discussion-on-question-by-thepopmachine-who-signed-the-captain-picard-day-sign).

Comment: The name on the bottom left looks like 'Mot', not 'Mox', to me anyway. If this is Mot the Barber then this question might also have to expand beyond the ship's children.