# Which props in Star Trek: Picard are reused from the original TNG show and films (if any)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes, props, star-trek-picard

We established here:

[Who signed the Captain Picard Day sign?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216437/who-signed-the-captain-picard-day-sign)

That the Picard Day sign from *Star Trek: Picard* is not the same as in *TNG*.

However we've also seen

> Worf's batleth, a model of the Stargazer, and a disassembled B4, with presumably other Easter eggs to come

**Which props in *Star Trek: Picard* are reused from the original TNG show and films (if any)?**

To be clear, I'm asking about props meant to represent a specific object recurring, not, for example, a random phaser or communicator.

Comment: Can this be edited to sound less like a list question?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, it's not a list question because I expect there to be very few props which actually purport to be from previous series.  However I'll narrow it to props meant to represent specific objects from the previous series.  I.e. not just a random phaser for example.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just "worried" anything seen on the show that is slightly reminiscent of TNG might count.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest and only was for the scene with B-4 in the draw at the Daystrom Institute. *Star Trek: Picard* Prop Master Jeff Lombardi talks about it [this official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBtrQHWCByw) (section begins at 2:24). I'm assuming this was from *Nemesis*.

[image: shot of data in a draw from Star Trek Picard]

He also mentions a lot of the real props were auctioned off long ago.