# Were the TNG-era uniforms re-created or reused?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, costume, star-trek-nemesis, star-trek-picard

In the first episode of *Star Trek: Picard*, "Redemption" we observe

> two dream sequences involving Picard and Data,

with uniforms from the *TNG* and *Nemesis* era.

Were these uniforms re-created or reused?

---

Related: [Which props in Star Trek: Picard are reused from the original TNG show and films (if any)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226532/which-props-in-star-trek-picard-are-reused-from-the-original-tng-show-and-films)

Comment: other than neither having an answer, how is one not a duplicate of the other?

Comment: @NKCampbell:   Well, because the other question asking if any prop from TNG was reused and this asks if the specific known STP prop comes from TNG.   They are not technically the same quesion, as evidenced by the fact that the answer submitted by Machavity to THIS question is NOT an answer to the other one.

Comment: the other question has an answer now ;)

Comment: Once again to justify the VTR: **They are not the same quesion, as evidenced by the fact that the answer submitted by Machavity to THIS question is NOT an answer to the other one.**

Answer (score 2):

## Almost certainly recreated.

[This IO9 article talks about Picard's admiral uniform](https://io9.gizmodo.com/up-close-with-star-trek-picards-newest-uniform-1839424255), which has not been seen before in canon (meaning they made it)

[image: ST: Picard Admiral uniform]

Then there's the fact that Brent Spiner is... well... Here's original TNG Data

[image: Classic Data]

And 30 years later, there's more of him to love. Here he is in *Picard*

[image: Picard and Data]

I doubt he would fit in uniforms from 1997 (TNG end) or 2002 (*ST: Nemesis*). Patrick Stewart might... but then there's the problem with the stuff itself. Clothes don't keep all that well and [Trek uniforms are routinely sold at auction](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_auctions).

Comment: Oh great, now somebody's going to have to ask why, in universe, do androids gain weight as they age?

Comment: @The Photon of all the suspension of disbelief you have to do for these sorts of situations, I could easily believe that Dr. Soong built slowing metabolism/weight gain into Data as he aged. It's established that he mimics several other human bodily functions (hair growth for example) so it's not completely unprecedented.

Comment: also - every indication is that Data is only appearing in Admiral Picard's dreams so 'accuracy' isn't necessarily a thing. Also also - Data's mother-droid doppleganger, Juliana Tainer did have built in aging - it's entirely possible Data adjusted his own design later to duplicate that so as to continue his own journey towards being more human

Comment: [Soong androids could age](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2020-01-24/star-trek-picard-old-data/)

Comment: Fully functional *in all* respects... @ThePhoton